# Commands in the new ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm learning the new ASP.NET 5 and I always see the new commands such as dnu, dnx and dnvm.
I'm still not sure when exactly I should use them if at all and what are the equivalent in the Visual Studio IDE.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use visual studio you shoulden't need to use the command line(if you dont want to), because visual studio does run the required commands for you. DNX Tools was made to enable x-plattform.

- **DNU** is for restoring project, and handling packages
- **DNVM** is the version manager that handles updating your DNX and the diffrent DNX Runtimes
- **DNX** command is your entry point to the runtime. To run an application you can use dnx

See more information at aspnet github wiki https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/DNX-structure

Comment: Yes, they realized that this is all too confusing and will "combine" these tools into [`dotnet`](http://dotnet.github.io/getting-started/) in RC2 which is scheduled to be released some time in Feb 2016 (if everything goes to plan).
This is in preview and isn't compatible with RC1 so don't install it willy-nilly.